# FormsAuthentication and Session cookie are lost in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

Hope someone can help me with this cause this problem has been bugging me for some time now.

I'm building a webshop and i'm integrating with a payment system hosted by a third party.
I have people review their order and when they click to proceed to entering in their credit card information i send them off through a secure connection to the payment system hosted on a different server, providing them with an "OK"-URL for sending them back to my site so i can close the order and do some other stuff, after a successful payment.

The problem is in Firefox when the remote server redirects back to my server the session id is lost and the forms authentication cookie is a completely different one, resulting in the user being logged out. This is not the case in IE, Safari and Chrome.

*Take from Fiddler2 before redirecting to remote host*

Request sent 342 bytes of Cookie data:

ASP.NET_SessionId=uusldflsxdecn0cfkoaw11tx; 
.ASPXAUTH=90109DFD47272DDB02905800582D[....]1878E319DED0DD63BBCA07C1114CD02EA32E7FE3C28BB3ECA07D3EF2131E7425AB6AF4D48777FBE9F965675CA9D0A8CF66AF4433F2CE045ADB419317F9C6F04D32669EF5EB87135B9949EC4462F2826BB6B

*After remote host redirects back to my server*

Request sent 298 bytes of Cookie data:

.ASPXAUTH=A73EE1BE818E1FE934F0AD8D48078E26646318DA24886CAE9[...]23AD63D679D0D838E746DE6357DBE0D3EA32A634873A62F399E1033138648314E83F1282A1949D64F4FC833948F1D3ABA5D997D8CABE3C6CA04256404A25FFC8C3D427A7640B488B01532314EE68

This seems really strange to me, and i haven't been able to find a way around this. My process for doing things works perfectly in IE, Safari and Chrome..

Is this a problem on the remote server? Is there something i'm doing wrong?
Is there a way of reconstructing the session somehow?

*From web.config:*

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1440"/>
</authentication>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, ..."  connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the above problem occurs, but after sleeping on it I figured out a pretty basic solution. I simply save the cookie values in my database before redirecting people to the remote host, and upon return i check the cookie values in the request and if there's a discrepancy i restore them with the ones from the database.

If the session key is lost upon return though, i have to make one redirect with the restored session cookies before accessing anything put in the session, for which i just use a RedirectToAction call, to another action in the same controller.

```
    private void SaveCookie(int orderId)
    {
        var sessionCookie = Request.Cookies.Get("ASP.NET_SessionId");
        var authCookie = Request.Cookies.Get(".ASPXAUTH");

        var ci = new CookieInformation
        {
            OrderId = orderId,
            SessionCookie = sessionCookie.Value,
            AuthCookie = authCookie.Value
        };

        Database.SetCookieInformation(ci);
        Logger.Info("Saved sessionId: " + sessionCookie.Value + " auth: " + authCookie.Value, this.ToString());
    }
```

And after returning:

```
    private void RestoreCookies(int orderId)
    {
        var reqSessionCookie = Request.Cookies.Get("ASP.NET_SessionId");
        var reqAuthCookie = Request.Cookies.Get(".ASPXAUTH");

        var savedCookie = Database.GetCookieInformation(orderId);


        if (reqSessionCookie.Value != savedCookie.SessionCookie || reqAuthCookie.Value != savedCookie.AuthCookie)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Clear();
            Response.Cookies.Set(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", savedCookie.SessionCookie));
            Response.Cookies.Set(new HttpCookie(".ASPXAUTH", savedCookie.AuthCookie));
        }

    }
```